# The proof of the Riesz representation thoerem for non-negative functionals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory, riesz-representation-theorem

I was reading Introduction to Geometric Metric Theory by Leon Simon. Here's the full statement of the Riesz representation theorem for non-negative functionals.

> Suppose $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, $\lambda:\mathcal{K}_{+}\to[0,\infty)$ with $\lambda(cf)=c\lambda(f)$, and $\lambda(f+g)=\lambda(f)+\lambda(g)$ whenever $c>0$ and $f,g\in\mathcal{K}_{+}$, where $\mathcal{K}_{+}$ is the of all non-negative continuous functions $f$ on $X$ with compact support. Then there is a Radon measure $\mu$ such that $\lambda(f)=\int_{X}f\,d\mu$ for all $f\in\mathcal{K}_{+}$.

The link below is the beginning of the proof. I have some problems understanding the last line. I could only see that $\mu(K)\leq\inf\{\lambda(g):g\in\mathcal{K}_{+},g\leq 1,g=1\mbox{ in a nhd. of }K\}$ by the definition straightforward. But I can't prove the converse. Could somebody give me some advice?

Edit: $W$ in $(**)$ is just an open set contained in another open set $U$.
[beginning of the proof](https://imgur.com/a/phzeAjp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeking a contradiction, assume that $$\mu(K)<A:=\inf\{\lambda(g):g\in \mathcal{K}_+,g\leqslant 1,g\equiv 1\text{ in a nbhd of }K\}.$$  Fix $$\mu(K)<a<A.$$   Since $$a=\mu(K)=\inf\{\mu(U):U\text{ open},U\supset K\},$$ $a$ is not a lower bound for $\{\mu(U):U\text{ open},U\supset K\}$, and there exists an open set $U$ containing $K$ such that $\mu(U)<a$. By replacing $U$ with a subset thereof, we can assume without loss of generality that $\overline{U}$ is compact and that there exists an open set $V$ such that $K\subset V\subset \overline{V}\subset U$.

By Urysohn's Lemma, there exists $g:X\to [0,1]$ which is continuous such that $g|_K\equiv 1$ and $g|_{X\setminus \overline{V}}\equiv 0$.  Then $g\in \mathcal{K}_+$, $g\leqslant 1$, and $\text{supp}(g)\subset U$.   Then $$A\leqslant \lambda(g)\leqslant \mu(U)<a<A,$$ a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! $\lambda(U)$ in the last line should be replaced by $\mu(U)$ right?

Comment: Yes. Thanks. Corrected.

Comment: Sorry, last question, why can you assume without loss of generality $\bar{U}$ is compact?

Comment: Because the space is locally compact, each $x\in X$ has an open neighborhood, say $U_x$, such that $\overline{U_x}$ is compact. Then $(U_x)_{x\in K}$ is an open cover of $K$. Therefore there exists a finite $L\subset K$ such that $K\subset \cup_{x\in L}U_x$. Since $L$ is finite, $\overline{\cup_{x\in L}U_x}=\cup_{x\in L}\overline{U_x}$ is compact. If necessary, we replace $U$ with $W:=U\cap \cup_{x\in L}U_x$. Then $\overline{W}\subset \overline{\cup_{x\in L}U_x}$ is compact and $\mu(W)\leqslant \mu(U)$ since $W\subset U$.

Comment: Get it. Thanks again!